# Sorting list using custom comparator not working

Tags: java, android, list, sorting

I want to sort list of users on the basis of three criteria.
So i have created custom comparator to sort list but its not working as i want

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator {
    List<Integer> user1Time = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> user2Time = new ArrayList<>();
    int user1Count, user2Count;
    ParseUser user1, user2;
    Date user1Date, user2Date;
    boolean user1Short, user2Short;
    private String TAG="CustomComparator";

    @Override
    public int compare(Object lhs, Object rhs) {
        user1 = (ParseUser) lhs;
        user2 = (ParseUser) rhs;


        user1Time = user1.getList("timeAvailable");
        user2Time = user2.getList("timeAvailable");


        //To compare Available time of both users with Searched Time

        if(user1Time!=null){
            user1Time.retainAll(Utils.availableTime);
            user1Count = user1Time.size();
        }else{
            user1Count=0;
        }

        if(user2Time!=null){
            user2Time.retainAll(Utils.availableTime);
            user2Count = user2Time.size();
        }else{
            user2Count=0;
        }



        Log.d(TAG, "compare: "+user1.getString("name")+" "+user1Count);
        Log.d(TAG, "compare: "+user2.getString("name")+" "+user2Count);



        //To compare lastSeen of both the users
        user1Date = user1.getDate("lastSeen");
        user2Date = user2.getDate("lastSeen");


        //To compare shortNotice avilablity of both the user
        user1Short = user1.getBoolean("shortNotice");
        user2Short = user2.getBoolean("shortNotice");

        if(user2Time!= null && user2Time!= null && user1Date!= null && user2Date!= null){
            if (user1Count>user2Count){
                if(user1Short){
                    if(user1Date.compareTo(user2Date)>0){
                        return -1;
                    }else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }else if (user1Date.compareTo(user2Date)>0){
                    return -1;
                }else if (user2Date.compareTo(user1Date)>0){
                    return 1;
                }
            }else if(user2Short){
                if(user2Date.compareTo(user1Date)>0){
                    return 1;
                }else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }else if (user2Date.compareTo(user1Date)>0){
                return 1;
            }else if (user1Date.compareTo(user2Date)>0){
                return -1;
            }
        }
            return 0;
    }
}
```

but its not working properly

i want to sort list in three ways array of integers,boolean and date
as you can see in my code.

Comment: `but its not working properly` define not `working properly`. please include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Use `thenComparing`

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Could you me more elaborate?

Comment: i mean it sort list but some times user with more time availablity is not coming at top even his shortNotice is true. I want user having better two out of three criteria or all the three.I works if time availablity list is small but if list extends more than 10 items it does not work

Comment: @YassinHajaj plz give me some example of thenComparing

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Data {
int A;
int B;
int C;

public int getA() {
    return A;
}

public void setA(int a) {
    A = a;
}

public int getB() {
    return B;
}

public void setB(int b) {
    B = b;
}

public int getC() {
    return C;
}

public void setC(int c) {
    C = c;
}
}

class Sorter {
public void sort(List<Data> dataList){
    Collections.sort(dataList,
            Comparator.comparingInt(Data::getA)
            .thenComparingInt(Data::getB)
            .thenComparingInt(data->data.C)
    );
}
}
```

here i use only `comparingInt` but you could do it with any kind of comparators.